# MySQLi -> insert_id unable to return value

Tags: php

I have this problem:

I do query, no error, data writed to the DB.

When i try to get the "insert_id" no data returned... but if i do "echo" function, write the value.

Code:

```
$insert_id = (int)$this -> conn -> insert_id;
echo '#'.$this -> conn -> insert_id.'#';
print_r($this -> conn);
die($insert_id);
```

Result:

```
#12#
mysqli Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 1
    ...
    [connect_errno] => 0
    [connect_error] => 
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [field_count] => 0
    ...
    [info] => 
    [insert_id] => 12
    ...
)
```

Why i cant get the ID from "$insert_id = (int)$this -> conn -> insert_id;" this!?

Thanks!

Comment: insert_id is already an int, could you try it without the casting? See if maybe PHP is putting the cast on the wrong object and causing you troubles(IE trying `((int)$this)->conn->insert_id` - error)

Comment: can you able to get the o/p in `$insert_id` without type casting as `(int)` ?

Comment: Whit or without casting, same problem!

@chresse, $this -> conn is the DB connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's indeed a funny question.

You need to read *die()*'s manual page to get your answer:

> status
> If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting.
>
> **If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed.** Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0 is used to terminate the program successfully.

Comment: Ok, this have sense! XD
Now... why if i do "return $insert_id" and after i do echo function, is returning ''?

Comment: some other simple error like this. In general, functions return values all right

Comment: In this case, return just ''. I will set it to work with echo... thaks! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Try `mysqli_insert_id()` - `$conn->insert_id`

Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: No. Do not suggest the old mysql_* functions to someone who is clearly using the superior and modern mysqli method.

Comment: He is using mysqli, take a moment to read the question and his code in order to advice him properly.

Comment: @scragar There is no indication that he ever said to use mysql_* functions. Look in his edit history. It all says mysqli_*

Comment: @Twister1002 if you edit the post within a short time of making it the edit doesn't show in the history, I believe the cut off is something like 5 minutes. After that it's an edit the community may vote on and enters public record, the same goes for the ability to delete posts, you can delete your own posts within a short time of making them without community approval.